# Dynamic class binding doesn't work in Vue

Tags: javascript, css, vuejs2, intersection-observer, dynamic-class

I'm using Vue2 and I face some problems with dynamic class binding (highlight in the navigation menubar the current section name in which the user is currently). I'm using the Intersection observerAPI which I initialize and let it loop over my components from the mounted() life hook. However, when I update the current section in my observer:

```
if (active.length) {
   this.activeEntry = active[0].target.childNodes[0].id
   console.log(this.activeEntry)
}
```

(For full code see below)
it prints the changes of the current sections "targetEntry" to the console, but...
my actual data "targetEntry" doesn't actually get updated/affected (Am I not able to change data from inside the observer?). I guess I mixe here some things up. How do I need to rewrite my observer functionality (i.e. make use of computed) to actually change my "targetEntry" data so the dynamic classes binding will be executed? I'm still a beginner to Vue and Javascript...

Many thanks in advance!

```
<template>
  <div id="Navigation-c">
    <ul>
      <li :class="{ active: activeEntry == 'Entry-c' }" v-scroll-to="'#Entry-c'"><font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-chevron-up" /></li>
      <li :class="{ active: activeEntry == 'Motivation-c' }" v-scroll-to="'#Motivation-c'"><p>Intro</p></li>
      <li :class="{ active: activeEntry == 'NeuralNetworks-c' }" v-scroll-to="'#NeuralNetworks-c'"><p>AI</p></li>
      <li :class="{ active: activeEntry == 'About-c' }" v-scroll-to="'#About-c'"><p>About</p></li>
      <li :class="{ active: activeEntry == 'Contact-c' }" v-scroll-to="'#Contact-c'"><p>Contact</p></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Navigation-c",
  data: () => ({
    activeEntry: '',
    observer: null
  }),
  methods: {

  },
  updated() {

  },
  mounted() {
    this.observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      function (entries) {
        const active = entries.filter((e) => e.isIntersecting);
        if (active.length) {
          this.activeEntry = active[0].target.childNodes[0].id
          console.log(this.activeEntry)
        }
      },
      { threshold: [0.5] }
    )
    // loop over components
    const matches = document.querySelectorAll("section.box");
    for (let i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
      this.observer.observe(matches[i]);
    }
  },
  computed: { 
    
  },
  created() {

  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.active {
  color: red !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) loses it's context inside of `new IntersectionObserver()` without the use of an arrow function.  Therefore attempting to assign `this.activeEntry` will not work unless you rewrite using the arrow function:

```js
mounted() {
    this.observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      (entries) => { // arrow function!
        const active = entries.filter((e) => e.isIntersecting);
        if (active.length) {
          this.activeEntry = active[0].target.childNodes[0].id
          console.log(this.activeEntry)
        }
      },
      { threshold: [0.5] }
    )
    // loop over components
    const matches = document.querySelectorAll("section.box");
    for (let i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
      this.observer.observe(matches[i]);
    }
  },
```